# How to fix the do-while loop containing function calls

Tags: c++

There seems to be a problem in my do-while loop. Setting aside any physical definition of the function I have right now, the user should input the coefficients of the cubic function, I.E. `a`,`b`,`P`, and `T`. The user then will input the initial guess, `v1`

Now at the loop, I will store `v1` to `v`, Then compute the new value of `v1` by the formula: `v1 = v - (fv/fv1)` 
Where the values of `fv` and `fv1` are determined from the function calls. The results are disturbing af.

Please help me guys on my loop! Also, please comment on my function definition. I just made that up after reading basic tutorials.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const double R = 0.082054;
double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);
double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double q =P*pow(v,3)-(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,2)+a*v-a*b;
    return q;
}
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double s =3*P*pow(v,2)-2*(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,1)+a;
    return s;
}
int main()
{
//INPUT STAGE!
cout << "Use gas constant, R: " << R << endl;

double a,b,P,T,Tc;
cout << "\nUse test value, a: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "\nUse test value, b: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "\nUse pressure, P (atm): ";
cin >> P;
cout << "\nUse absolute temperature, T (K): ";
cin >> T;

double v,v1,fv,fv1,N,e;
int iteration = 0;
cout << "\nUse initial guess for molal volume, v: ";
cin >> v;
cout << "\nUse maximum number of iterations, N: ";
cin >> N;
cout << "\nUse tolerance, e: ";
cin >> e;
cout << "\n";

do
{
    v = v1;
    fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);
    fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);
    v1 = v-(fv/fv1);
    cout << iteration+1 << setw(12) << v << setw(16) << v1 << setw(16) << abs(v1-v) << endl;
    iteration++;
}
while(iteration<N && abs(v1-v)>e);

return 0;
}
```

Below is the unwanted results that I'm getting (the header was just for formatting the output):

[image]

On the picture, I have set maximum iterations, N = 5. So it prints(loop) 5 times. But I get unwanted results.

UPDATE: I have managed to solve this by initializing v1=0. Thanks to Mr. UnholySheep.

Comment: whats the problem with the do while loop?

Comment: You can just describe your problem in normal English, I mean don't use capital letter everywhere.

Comment: thanks man for the edit!

Comment: Your variable `v1` is not initialized, so it has an indeterminate value, so `v = v1;` leads to *undefined behavior* in the function calls (`fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);` and `fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);`) afterwards

Comment: WOW! JUST WOW! It's been weeks of me figuring this sh*t out. Now the only thing that's missing after all is just a "v1=0". Thanks man! 

Now i can proceed further with this school requirement. Will ask for more queries in the future guys! hehe!

Comment: Sir UnholySheep, how can i break my do-while loop when fv1 = 0 (for it will be undefined)? I try to insert after the calculation of fv1 (inside the do-while loop) the if statement with break but it prints unexpected results as well.

Comment: One question per question please - if you have a new problem then consider starting a new question. Please also read: [ask].

Comment: Oh i'm very sorry sir it was a honest mistake. Thank you everyone!